# Sum values received from foreach loop php

Tags: php, logic

I want to sum the values in my custom function, where the argument/parameter received is a variable from the foreach loop in another file.

Below is the code:

```
// $value is the looped variable from another function
function custom_function($value) {
  // simple logic
  $var = [];
  $var += $value;
  print_r($var);

  // using array logic
  $array = [];
  $array[] = $value;
  print_r($array);
}
```

The issue is, using any of the `print_r` I'm getting the output as:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 100
)
Array
(
    [0] => 200
)
```

What I need is 300, i.e. the sum of 100 + 200 the reason I suspect is the `$value` is the looped variable.

Comment: Why do you need an array? It can be easily done without it.

Comment: I don't need an array, as mentioned above I need to sum `$value` which is a looped element from the foreach loop in another file. The output array is received and not generated :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a static variable to maintain the sum between function calls:

```
function custom_function($value) {
    static $var = 0;
    $var += $value;
    echo "$var\n";
}

custom_function(100);
custom_function(200);
```

Output:

```
100
300
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/oj7Hd)

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = array('10','20','30');
$result = array();
$temp = 0;
foreach($a as $v)
{
  $temp  = $v+$temp; 
  array_push($result,$temp);

}
echo end($result);
echo '<br>';
print_r($result);
```

I am thinking `$a` is an array of which values are passed. Try doing this if you dont want to change much of the logic just create 2 temporary variables

Comment: I can't do `foreach($a` as I'm only getting the `$v` here, the above solution will work, but at the place where `foreach` loop is created, what I'm trying to achieve is, receiving the $v and now I need to sum all the values that my `$v` iteration is receiving.

Comment: @RishiKulshreshtha Yes then just simply use the two lines inside foreach that will work for you that will save all your previous stored values and can even add, if you just want only addition of all the variables passed you can use end function after pushing it

Answer (score 0):

You can use **array_sum** to calculate the sum of array values

```
function custom_function($value) {
  // simple logic
  $var = [];
  $var += $value;
  print_r($var);
  print_r(array_sum($var));
}

 $array = array('100','200');
 $res= array(); //declare a new array 
 foreach($array as $val)
  {
    array_push($res,$val);  // push each element to newly created array
  }
 custom_function($res); //call custom function to calculate the sum of array elements
```